# Will the change in the Dimorphos orbit affect the long-term orbit of Didymos?

Tags: orbital-motion

Will the change in the Dimorphos orbit affect the long-term orbit of Didymos?
The orbit of Dimorphos has changed by 32 minutes will this affect the orbit of the major asteroid it orbits

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes. From the solar point of view, the Didymos/Dimorphos binary is effectively a single body. An impulse applied to Dimorphos affects the orbit of that body.